# Solve Non-lineaer Differential Equation (Step-by-Step)

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations

Being able to solve Linear and Non-liner differentional equations is an important part of mathematics. I am trying to work out the exact solution for this non-linear differential equation and require some help from the community (Please could you provide the full step-by-step-solution), I want to undertstand the mathematics and be able to apply this do other questions.

$$\dfrac {du}{dx}+ u^2 = 0  \tag 1 $$

Boundary conditions $0<x<1; u(0)=1$

What is the exact solution?

Comment: What do you mean by that? Please clarify

Comment: Could you show me the full procedure on how to do the question with clear steps and proof. Could you apply the boundary conditions and show me how you get to the exact solution. I am new to this subject area.

Answer (score 2):

Note that you can rewrite it as:
$$-\frac{1}{u^2}\frac{du}{dx} = 1,$$
and you might recognize on the left-hand side the derivative with respect to $x$ of $x\mapsto \frac{1}{u(x)}$. Indeed, by the chain rule, denoting $f(x)=\frac 1x$:
$$\frac{d}{dx}\bigl(f(u(x))\bigr) = \frac{df}{dx}(u(x))\cdot\frac{du}{dx}(x) = -\frac{1}{u^2}\frac{du}{dx}.$$

Thus integrating over $x$ on both sides gives, for the left hand side:
$$\int_0^x -\frac{1}{u(s)^2}\frac{du}{dx}(s)ds = \int_0^x \frac{d}{dx}\bigl( f(u(s))\bigr) ds = f(u(x)) - f(u(0))$$
and the right hand side:
$$\int_0^x 1ds = x.$$
Equating both and using the condition $u(0)=1\implies f(u(0))=1$:
$$f(u(x)) - 1 = \frac{1}{u(x)} -1 = x,$$
$$\iff \frac{1}{u(x)} = x+1 \iff u(x) = \frac{1}{x+1}.$$
The last equality is possible since $0\leq x \leq 1$.

Comment: For $u^\prime +u = 0$, do the same thing, only $u^\prime/u$ is not the derivative of $1/u(x)$ this time. You should be able to recognize a well known function though. What do you mean by "proof both exact solutions"?

Comment: I showed you for $u^\prime + u^2=0$, it is exactly the same method, just look into the classical derivatives formulas you know.

Comment: Hi Rem, could change your working to Leibnitz notation

Comment: @Nathan Done, hope it helps.

Comment: Hi Rem, you inergration is not clear and is confusing me. Could you do it step by step like the example below. I would appreciate this, I can’t seem to get my head around this concept

Comment: @Nathan I tried to add a little more details but I can't do better if you don't tell me what is "this concept" and what you don't understand really.

Answer (score 1):

This is an answer to your question in the comments. Please, keep in mind for the future, provide any attempts you have made, any progress, everything you have tried to solve the problem. Where did you stuck, what was the difficulty? MSE is not a place to simply solve your homework for you ...

Regarding your question about the solution of $u^\prime + u = 0$. Apply the same logic as @Rem explained and also here, think about the problem first:

You want to find a function such that adding its own derivative would results in zero, i.e., they would cancel each other out. So, we need two identical terms with an opposite sign. How about something like -1 + 1 = 0? It seems like we are looking for a function which is very similar to itself when differentiating. Do you have a clue? If not, you can solve this ODE by separation of variables:

First, write your ODE in Leibnitz notation
$$
\frac{\mathrm{d}u}{\mathrm{dx}} + u = 0 \\
\frac{\mathrm{d}u}{\mathrm{dx}} = -u.
$$
We can already see that we are looking for a function which after differentiation stays the same, only changes its sign. Still no clue yet? Change the variables such that the terms containing the variable $u$ are on one side, and the terms containing the dependent variable $x$ on the other side:
$$
\frac{1}{\mathrm{d}u} = -1 \mathrm{d}x.
$$
Now you want to integrate both sides over $x$, so we change the dependent variable from $x$ to $s$ to avoid confusion and write
$$
\int_0^x\frac{1}{u}\mathrm{d}u = \int_0^x-1\mathrm{d}s.
$$
This is easy, think about what function differentiated results in the fraction you see on the l.h.s? Exactly, it's the logarithmic function. If $u = \ln(u)$, then $u^\prime = \frac{1}{u}$, hence we have
$$
\ln(u) + c_1 = -x + c_2.
$$
Bring the coefficient $c_1$ to the right side, apply the exponential function on both sides, et voilà, there's your solution:
$$
%\mathrm{e}^{\ln(u)} = \mathrm{e}^{-x} \cdot \underbrace{\mathrm{e}^{c_1 - c_2}}_{= c_3}\\[1em]
u(x) = \mathrm{e}^{-x} + c_3.
$$

If you want you can check your solution, just take the derivative of this function and add it to the function $u(x)$: $\mathrm{-e}^{-x}+\mathrm{e}^{-x} = 0$.

I forgot, you are given the boundary condition $u(0) = 1$. Apply this to your function and solve for the constant $c_3$:
$$
1 = \mathrm{e}^{-0} + c_3 \quad \Longleftrightarrow \quad c_3 = 0.
$$

Comment: Dear Eldorado i dont understand how Rem has solve the non-linear differential equation with du/dx +u^2 = 0. His working out is very complicated and doesnt go into enough detail and I dont understand it. Could you redo the question with your working out please as you done for the question below? Kindest Regards, Nathan

Comment: Could you also give me an overview on different finite element methods used to solve linear and non-linear odes and there benfits? I want to be able to model an system in the future but I need to grasp the fundemetals first. Kindes Regards Nathan

Comment: Reducing the Navier Stokes Equation in the X- Direction- I have also got an question on the Navier stokes equation, I think it is specialist area as no one is able to help. If you have time, please could you take a look at that. Thank You

Comment: On your first comment, do you still need help after @Rem has changed the answer according to your comments?

Comment: Please post a new question regarding Finite Elements and Navier Stokes. And if you do so, please indicate specifically how we can help and show us your thoughts and approaches.

Comment: Eldorado, I am trying to solve this non-linear equation for the above ode du/dx +U^2 = 0 but I am getting really confused with his notation and steps, could you place make it clearer like your example